How to substitute variables in a Python raw string?
I want the code snippet below to output a plot, with fraction 2.345 / 3.456 to be rendered using latex at the point (0.1, 0.9). I'm using python raw string along with f-strings in the call to Matplotlib's Axes.text API. I can't seem to make the variable be substituted correctly.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

def main():
  fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=False)
  strtime = "2.345"
  arp_strtime = "3.456"

  ax1.text(0.1, 0.9, rf"$\frac{strtime}{arp_strtime}$")

The last line above outputs a fraction of the variable names instead of the values assigned to them.
